# access model using dir

Tags: python, torch

I have used [This link](https://github.com/bshillingford/python-torchfile) to load [Torch Model](https://github.com/satoshiiizuka/siggraph2016_colorization) and access it to get it's layers trained weights, i tried many times but i can't use **dir** command to access it's **layers weights**, so what am i missing ? is that the wrong way to access them ? can any one help me, and this is the code and it's output.

```
import torchfile
o = torchfile.load('colornet.t7')
print dir(o['model'])
```

**output**

```
['backwardnodes', 'bg', 'fg', 'forwardnodes', 'innode', 'modules', 'nInputs', 'outnode', 'torch_typename', 'train', 'verbose']
```

Comment: o['mode']['modules'][2][weight] ?

Comment: thanks @debzsud i already tried to print o['model']['models'] and it gives me some values but i dont know this values belongs to which layers or which networks , can i find some thing that enables me to access networks and then it's layers and finally the weights?